# Why I can't override a method from an extension of UIViewController in another UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm working on an ios `swift` app and I'm introducing handling of shake gestures in my app. I want to handle shaking all around the app besides one panel. On this specific panel I want to invoke a completely different function. So first I wrote an extension to UIViewController so that the shake gesture is supported everywhere else:

```
extension UIViewController:MotionDelegate {

override public func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
            print("I'm in extension")
            self.showAlertMessage("", message: "I'm in extension") //this invokes an alert message 
        }
}
}
```

and then in the panel that I want to handle it differently I wrote:

```
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {

        showAlertMsg("Yes!", message: "This is some random msg")
    }
}
```

Now the problem is as follows:

when I shake the phone on the screen that I want to behave differently - I see the alert msg with message `this is some random msg`. But when this screen appears on the screen (and it does for a couple seconds) and I shake the phone again - suddenly it shows the popup `I'm in extension`. I want to avoid showing the 2nd popup. The problem is that it does not recognize my overrided method when there is a popup up front with a first message. In other cases (when there is no popup) everything works fine. This is my `showAlertMsg` function:

```
func showAlertMsg(title: String, message: String, delay: Double){


    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    let delay = delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    })

}
```

Is there anything I could do to avoid showing the popup from extension while displaying the popup from the main controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have overridden in panel an extension for `UIViewController`. 
Then you present `UIAlertController`, which has not overridden method.
What you may do, is to make an extension for `UIAlertController` and handle this function.